# Обновление экрана python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно провернуть обновление виджетов на экране приложения python kivy? Если конкретнее, то по нажатию кнопки, должен появляться обновлённый gridlayout с только-что добавленным элементом. Как это можно правильно реализовать?

Запуск программы:

```
def initialize(self):
        screen = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical', padding = 10, spacing = 20)
        top = ScreenTop().draw_top()
        wallets = ScreenWallets().draw_wallets()
        expenses = ScreenExpenses().draw_expenses()
        screen.add_widget(top)
        screen.add_widget(wallets)
        screen.add_widget(expenses)

        return screen

    def build(self):
        return self.initialize()
```

Построение GridLayout:

```
class ScreenExpenses:
    def draw_expenses(self):
        expenses_grid = GridLayout(cols = 4, size_hint = (1, .47), spacing = 5)
        expenses = db.get_items('expense')
        placed = 0

        for expense in expenses:
            placed += 1
            expenses_grid.add_widget(Button(text = '{0}\n({1}р.)'.format(expense[0], expense[1]), \
                                            background_color = (.96, .83, 0, 1), background_normal = '', font_size = 14, \
                                            on_press = lambda a: self.open_expense()))
        if len(expenses) < 20:
            expenses_grid.add_widget(Button(text = 'Добавить', background_color = (0, .57, .93, 1), background_normal = '', \
                                            on_press = lambda a: self.add_category()))
        for null in range(20 - placed):
            expenses_grid.add_widget(Widget())

        return expenses_grid

    def open_expense(self):
        mw = ModalView(size_hint = (.7, .5))
        mw.open()


    def add_category(self):
        mw = NewExpenseModal(size_hint = (.7, .5))
        mw.add_widget(mw.initialize())
        mw.open()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очистить объект `instance_grid_layout` (`instance_grid_layout.clear_widgets()`) и добавить новые виджеты в `instance_grid_layout.add_widget(widget)`.

Comment: а можно ли как-нибудь обновить все виджеты на экране?

Comment: У тебя неправильное понятие о Kivy. Зачем обновлять виджеты, если они обновляются автоматически при изменении их свойств? Если хочешь обновить список элементов в `GridLayout`, то я уже дал ответ на этот вопрос. Просто используешь цикл по элементам из  `instance_grid_layout.children`